# A theorem of Tate

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

In Lang's "Real and Functional Analysis", he gives the following as the first problem of chapter XIV, which he says is due to Tate:

> Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces, and let $f:E\rightarrow F$ be a map with the following property.  There exists a number $C>0$ such that for all $x,y\in E$ we have $$|f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)|\leq C$$  Show that there exists a unique linear map $g:E\rightarrow F$ such that $g-f$ is bounded in the sup norm.  [Hint: Show that the limit $$g(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(2^n x)}{2^n}$$ exists.]

I do not think this is correct as stated.  My counterexample is $E=F=\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ such that $f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)=0$.  Such an $f$ satisfies [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), and the $g(x)$ derived as in the problem statement will be equal to $f$.  However, with no regularity conditions on $f$, it is well known that it need not be linear.  Hence the conclusion is false.

My questions are:

1. Have I missed anything in my critique?
2. What are the correct hypotheses for the theorem of Tate?

I would also appreciate a reference to Tate's work if possible, but I care about this less that the above points.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $g=f$ in your example?

Comment: Related problem on Math Overflow, with references: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30798/approximately-linear-functions

Comment: @Dunham $f(2x)/2 = f(x+x)/2 = (f(x)+f(x))/2=f(x)$.  Inductively, $f(2^n x)/2^n = f(x)$, so the limit $g(x)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the paper of Hyers (*On the Stability of the Linear Functional Equation*), he defines solutions of $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ to be **linear functions**. Using this definition clarifies what is being asked in the problem. However, the wording in Lang's book is indeed poor (unless I missed this definition somewhere).

Also, Lang has essentially the same problem in his algebra book (3rd ed., p.598), where it says that $g$ should be an additive function.